# Getting better Pefromance using BLOB, on JAVA

Tags: java, performance, blob

My question is not related to how to do something, it's more of how to help improve performance. I apologize for the long post, but I thought since this is about performance, that i should post all details about what I'm doing to see if anyone can help.

I have to make a program that gets info from 2 different databases, creates a metadata, its corresponding BLOB(pdf file) and zips it.
The metadata file is only created if the BLOB object was found in the database. I have managed to do so, but problem is sometimes I might have up to 80k results on my query and it may take as long as 20 hours to do so, which is ridiculous considering each blob object is no larger than 100 KB.

I have a transactional database (lets call it TEQ8P) where all the ID's and the info for the metadata is stored. I queried the data by date and status (which sucks but i don't have any other filter, that was the requirement)

```
TEQ8P.openConnection();
Boolean flag = TEQ8P.ExecuteQuery("select tr.legaltransnumber, cc.country_code, tr.transnumber,    tr.postingdate, tr.transdate from EQUATE.transheader tr inner join   companycode_country cc on tr.tocompanycode = cc.company_code where tr.transtype = 'IC' and   tr.transdate between to_date("  + date + ", 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date(" + nextday  + ", 'DD/MM  /YYYY')");

public Boolean ExecuteQuery(String query) {
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
                return false;
            rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            rowset.populate(rs);
            metadata = rs.getMetaData();              
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();   
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            HLog.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
            //System.out.println(query);            
        }
        finally 
        {
            closeConnection();
        }
}
```

I am using JAVA 1.5 (per requirement again) so I downloaded the cachedrowsetimp jar from oracle, so once I finish querying data I save it to memory and close the connection.

After that I start moving through the cachedrowset and query every ID on the Warehouse DB. I can't do a select "where in" because there is no way to tell if all id's will be found and an "in" would only return the items that it finds, and I wouldn't know which items it didn't find. But if you have any suggestion please!

So I use preparedStatement to use bind variables on ORACLE and start writing the blob object.

My first question, is there a better way to write blob files? A faster way?

```
if(flag)    
    {
        String Query = "select wh.transnumber, wh.image from EQUATEWH.legalimage wh where wh.transnumber = ?";
        WEQ8I.openConnection();
        WEQ8I.setPreparedStmt(Query);
        WEQ8I.WriteBlobs(PDF, TEQ8P.getRowsSet(), IC_FILE);     
        WEQ8I.closePrepStmt();
        WEQ8I.closeConnection();
        FileUtils.createZip(prop.getProperty("ZIPDIR_IC"), lsize, prop.getProperty("ZIPNAME_IC"));  

public void WriteBlobs(String path, CachedRowSetImpl set, IMP_File IC_FILE)
{
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        while(set.next())
            {                   
                pstmt.setString(1, set.getString(3));
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
                {
                    System.out.println("invoice " + set.getString(3) + "was not found on W database");
                    ErrorFile.writeErrorFile(set.getString(3));
                }
                else
                {
                    //getting the name of the PDF file, if no ID use legaltransnumber
                    String ID = set.getString(1);
                    if(ID == null)
                    {
                        ID = set.getString(3);
                    }
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        FileOutputStream fos = null;
                        try
                        {
                            Blob blob = rs.getBlob(2);
                            InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();
                            fos = new FileOutputStream(path + ID + ".pdf");
                            int i = 0;
                            while ((i = is.read()) != -1) 
                            {
                                fos.write(i);
                            }
                            fos.close();
                            is.close();
                            IC_FILE.fillIMPFile("IC", ID, set.getString(3), set.getString(2), set.getString(5));
                        }catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            ErrorFile.writeErrorFile(set.getString(3));
                        }
                    }                           
                }
                rs.close();                 
            }
        IC_FILE.writeFile();

    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem when trying to create Record: " + path);
        HLog.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        try
        {
            ErrorFile.writeErrorFile(set.getString(3));
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            HLog.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

If the query found a result for that ID on the WarehouseDB AND the image is not null (meaning it won't go to the null exception), I create the metadafile which is the IC_FILE.
the IC_FILE does not write a file, it saves everything into memory and when it finishes it writes the file, I thought this could help improve performance since it wouldn't have to do I/O operations on every file, just once, using IC_FILE.writefile().

To create the metadatafile, I also have to (per requirement again) get the container name from a file. to retrieve the container name I have to use 3 fields from the Transactional database, concatenate them and search for them in that file. 
this is how I create the IMP file, first to get data from each record:

```
public void fillIMPFile(String type, String ID, String ID2, String companyCode, String date)
{
    date = date.substring(0, 10);
    date = date.replace("-", "/");
    date = date.substring(5, 7) +  "/" + date.substring(8, 10) + "/" + date.substring(0, 4);
    String Name =  prop.getProperty("NAME");
    String info = prop.getProperty(type);   
    String DOS = Name + info + ID + ".";
    String NOTES = Name + " " + info + " ";
    info += getContainer(companyCode, date, type);


    if(type.equals("IC"))
    {
        String desc = prop.getProperty("DESC_PDF");
        DOS += "pdf";
        NOTES += desc + " " + ID + " " + ID2;

        buffer += info + "\t" + date + "\t" + date + "\t" + DOS + "\t" + NOTES + "\t"
                 + NOTES  + "\t" + ID2;
    }
```

To get the containers I use the properties object, but I guess there might be better choices? a hash map maybe?

```
public String getContainer(String companyCode, String Date, String type)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    Date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    //mal siempre pondra 2012
    String data = type + companyCode + Date;
    String container = containers.getProperty(data);

    if(container == null)
    {
        data = type + "WW" + Date;
        container = containers.getProperty(data);
    }
    return container;
}
```

finaly to write the file:

```
public void writeFile()
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(File, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(buffer);
        bw.close();
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        HLog.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

thanks!! 
Daniel

Comment: forgot to mention, the container file has 2700 container names, so it searches for it one by one :S

Answer (score 0):

fixed...using bind variables and creating more than 1 container file for each year